# Django Pipeline node cannot find lessc

Tags: python, django, node.js, less, django-pipeline

I'm configuring [Django Pipeline](https://django-pipeline.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), which I have done before on Linux without issues. On OSX I get the following issue when using Less:

```
CompilerError: env: node: No such file or directory
```

The message comes from the stderr of the command pipeline is trying to execute:

```
/usr/local/bin/lessc  /foo/bootstrap.less /bar/bootstrap.css
```

Which I can run from the terminal without any issues with the Python virtualenv active (or not). I have tried installing lessc with and without the -g flag.

It seems node and lessc are setup fine on the system and PIPELINE_LESS_BINARY is set correctly but no joy.

Node and Less were installed with `brew` on OSX 10.10 (yosemite)

Any ideas?

Comment: stupid question `env node` does result in node being executed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume the env your django commands operates on does not have the PATH setted correctly for node, a hacky solution could be to locate the node binary with `which node` and then link it to /usr/bin:

```
sudo ln -s node_binary_path /usr/bin/node
```

Comment: Yes this worked. `node` was in `/usr/local/bin/` and `env` was in `/usr/bin/env`, so even though it worked from the shell either Python's path is wrong or `env` does something odd.